# $.post и $.ajax

Tags: jquery

Народ, подскажите, в jQuery запрос $.post - синхронный?? 
знаю, что в $.ajax есть атрибут async, а что с $.post ??

Answer (score 5):

$.post() и $.get() - это сокращенные варианты функции $.ajax() и по умолчанию  все запросы происходят асинхронно.

P.S. От себя бы добавил - если вы используете Ajax несколько раз в скрипте, то лучше использовать полный вариант. Плюс ко всему, можно сформировать общие настройки для запросов, используя [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/). Тогда вы избавитесь от излишеств в коде, по сути получите те же сокращенные варианты, но застрахуетесь от непредвиденного поведения в выполнении скрипта. Например, зарание прописываем путь к php-handler, формат в котором будем получать ответ, тип выполняемого запроса (GET или POST), ну и скажем синхронную/асинхронную передачу данных:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: '/handler.php',
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'

});
```

Всё! Теперь мы в любом ajax-запросе, только добавляем передаваемые данные и обрабатываем полученный ответ:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {key: val},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: спасибо за совет!
аяксом я вообще не пользуюсь. по умолчанию - т.е. нельзя изменить эту настройку именно для $.post???

Comment: @deathr0w777, Насколько мне известно - нет. Хотя, почему б не попробовать:

    $.post('handler.php', {async: false}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

А зачем вам синхронный режим? Это ведь может привести к блокировке страницы, пока запрос не будет полностью выполнен.